# Why did Darth Vader not send stormtroopers to execute Luke and Han near the Sarlacc pit?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Apparently Boba Fett was too weak and so was his gang. Why should Vader not have sent his troopers to take out Luke, Han, Chewbacca, and R2D2 who later helped Luke to escape? That way he could have prevented Boba from dying, and the Star Wars series could have been ended with Imperial victory.

Comment: Vader didn't know that they were there.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I thought Boba was hired by Vader and there were communications between them.

Comment: Boba Fett was hired by Vader to help catch Skywalker, but his primary mission was to capture Solo for Jabba the Hutt, which he'd been trying to do since the first movie. After how things went down in Empire, I'm pretty sure that Boba Fett wouldn't have been inclined to create any more headaches for himself by contacting the Empire.

Comment: Good question. Fett was working for Vader in the previous film and knows he's taking him to Jabba. It's quite likely that having escaped from Cloud City, Vader would be expecting to re-acquire Luke on Tatooine rescuing Han.

Comment: @Richard - Fett working for Vader was a short term contract, and only taken so he could fulfill the contract with Jabba for Han. He wasn't on a permanent retainer.

Comment: @DVK - The wider question is why Vader wasn't spying on Jabba.

Comment: @Richard - Haven't you seen Ep3? He knew that The Force would bring Luke to him. Why bother to .. y'know... actually put in any effort. Just use the Force.

Comment: Also, if you really want an answer, dig into Bounty Hunter trilogy. I'm too wiped to go re-read it but they had a whole deep storyline over what everyone and their grandmother's pet Rancor was doing on/around/about Tattooine around the time. Vader included, I think.

Comment: Stormtroopers couldn't execute fish in a barrel.

Comment: @WadCheber - Obi-Wan disagrees with you.

Comment: @DVK - he always disagrees with the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disney Canon

I don't know <strike>and don't care</strike> what Disney canon says on the matter. Likely nothing since to the best of my knowledge no new Disney material covers ROTJ time period except actual Episode VI film/novelization; and they say nothing of the matter. Earlier script drafts detailed in "Making of..." book had some interesting ideas but nothing I found useful to answer this question.

### EU/Legends

- In Zahn's work (first Thrawn trilogy), we know that the Emperor DID cover his bases - he sent Emperor's Hand, a trained Force-sensitive assassin Mara Jade to keep an eye on the Jabba's bachelor pad and make sure Luke gets executed or captured (for obvious reasons, the Emperor didn't much care about Han's fate).

  Mara Jade ran into the typical Jedi problem: Jabba was a Hutt. Stubborn, annoying, and not prone to falling for Jedi Mind Tricks. So, he - for some unstated reason - refused Mara Jade entry onto the barge the day of execution.

  According to Luke's own Force influenced dreams, if Mara had been there on the barge, he'd have been Sarlacc nutrients. So, in a way, Jabba saved Luke's life. He should have gotten the Force Ghost at the end of the film instead of Anakin :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there's also a Long Hand of Vader floating around in Bounty Hunter trilogy, but need to check details.

Comment: Also, not worth adding as an answer, but Vader didn't give a fig over whether Fett lived or died. AND, Fett didn't *ever* have a gang (BHG doesn't count as "his" gang despite his fake association with them). He had individual business associates.... sometimes.

Comment: "first Thrawn trilogy"? Is there more than 1 Thrawn trilogy?

Comment: @RedCaio - well, the second one is a duology, so I guess the "1st" is unnecessary :)

Answer (score 2):

Because that would provoke the Hutt cartel. They are a vast and enourmous criminal Syndicate, interfering with their business would likely cause war

Comment: Except that he did **exactly that** in the previous episode. Vader's troops were all over Mos Eisley, hassling the locals, looking for droids.

Comment: @Richard - is THAT what they called R&R in a den of vice those days?